# How to update just ifupdown package?

Tags: 12.04, networking, apt, updates

We are trying to add some ipv6 addresses to our 12.04 servers. We can add the values to /etc/network/interfaces just fine, but when we try to run "ifup bond1:1" it fails. Here is the error message we get:

```
error: "net.ipv6.conf.bond1:1.autoconf" is an unknown key
Failed to bring up bond1:1.
```

I'm pretty sure it's related to this bug because we using the alias in our config: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1347246

I see they've fixed it in recent ubuntu versions. How can I install an updated version of ifupdown? It doesn't show up as an apt update for our current release and we can't do a full version update to 16.04 at this time.

Comment: You can try to build it from source, but chances are, it will require rebuilding half the OS. I'm not sure it's worth the trouble, especially since 12.04 will go EOL in about 5 months.

Comment: That was my thought too... Is there another tool that can bring up a newly configured interface without ifup?